# Salesforce Lead Allocation based on Region

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

My requirement is to automatically assign a **Lead** to **Sales Representative** based on Region. 
A **region** is made of many countries. I want Salesforce to identify the region based on the country and assign the lead to Sales Representative accordingly.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to write a Trigger or workflow to stamp Region on a field (A custom field created) on Lead Record .

Write Assignment rules based on Region to assign these leads as per Region.

For Trigger you can create a Region Object and have child objects Country linked to Same .Or other way could be use custom setting and store for regions different countries that belong to Region.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can I achieve the same by using territory

Comment: Territory management is broader concept .It will affect sharing rules so just for simple lead assignment ,I wont recommend same.